# How to serve file from go embed

Tags: go

I have a static directory, containing a `sign.html` file :

```
//go:embed static
var static embed.FS
```

It is served that way and works fine :

```
fSys, err := fs.Sub(static, "static")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
mux.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(fSys)))
```

On some routes though (for instance: `/sign`), I want to do some checks before serving the page. This is my handler :

```
func (h Handler) ServeSignPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    publicKey := r.URL.Query().Get("publicKey")
    err := h.Service.AuthorizeClientSigning(r.Context(), publicKey)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // this is where I'd like to serve the embed file
    // sign.html from the static directory
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "sign.html")
    return nil
}
```

Unfortunately, the `ServeFile` displays not found. How can I serve the file from the file server within that `ServeSignPage` ?

Comment: In your mux, route the request to your handler instead of the file server. In your handler, hand off to the FileServer instead of calling `http.ServeFile`. `ServeFile` uses the local file system, *not* your embedded file system (notice it doesn't even take a reference to the embedded FS).

Comment: How do you handle off to the fileserver ?

Comment: Also isn't `http.FileServer(http.FS(fSys))` a reference to the embed FS since fSys is made from the embed FS ?

Comment: thanks Cerise, was way less complicated than expected.

Comment: If you have answers to provide, they need to be posted below as answers. Please don't edit answers into your questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1**

[Read the file](https://pkg.go.dev/embed#FS.ReadFile) to a slice of bytes.  [Write the bytes](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Write) to the response.

```
p, err := static.ReadFile("static/sign.html")
if err != nil {
    // TODO: Handle error as appropriate for the application.
}
w.Write(p)
```

**Option 2**

If the path for the `ServeSignPage` handler is the same as the static file in the file server, then delegate to the file server.

Store the file server in a package-level variable.

```
var staticServer http.Handler

func init() {
    fSys, err := fs.Sub(static, "static")
    if err != nil {
          panic(err)
    }
    staticServer = http.FileServer(http.FS(fSys)))
}
```

Use the static server as the handler:

```
 mux.Handle("/", staticServer)
```

Delegate to the static server in `ServeSignPage`:

```
func (h Handler) ServeSignPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    publicKey := r.URL.Query().Get("publicKey")
    err := h.Service.AuthorizeClientSigning(r.Context(), publicKey)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    staticServer.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    return nil
}
```