# Passing an embed.FS to http.FileServer only results in 404 errors

Tags: go

Using the *embed* feature of Go I want to serve CSS files via `http.FileServer` at `/static/css/`. As of now, this only results in 404 errors.

Following the comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70069776/220225 I set it up as such:

main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "foobar/pkg/db"
    "foobar/pkg/svc"
    "foobar/static"
)

func main() {
    db, err := db.NewMongoStore()
    panicOnError(err, "unable to connect to db:")

    httpdService := svc.NewHttpdService(db, static.StaticFiles)
    httpdService.RunServer()
}
```

static/embed.go:

```golang
package static // import "foobar/static"

import "embed"

//go:embed all:css
var StaticFiles embed.FS
```

pkg/svc/httpd.go:

```golang
package svc // import "foobar/pkg/svc"

import (
    "embed"
    "io/fs"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "foobar/pkg/model"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type httpdService struct {
    DB            model.FoobarDB
    staticFiles   embed.FS
}

// Static file server as package level variable
var staticServer http.Handler

func NewHttpdService(db model.FoobarDB, staticFiles embed.FS) model.HttpdService {
    return httpdService{
        staticFiles:   staticFiles,
        DB:            db,
    }
}

func (hs httpdService) RunServer() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    fSys, err := fs.Sub(hs.staticFiles, ".")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("error in static file server: ", err)
    }
    staticServer = http.FileServer(http.FS(fSys))
    r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(staticServer)

    // TMP
    println("content of static.StaticFiles:")
    fs.WalkDir(fSys, ".", func(path string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        println(path, "// IsDir:", d.IsDir())
        return nil
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":12345", r))
}
```

Output of the TMP statements show that the embedFS looks good:

```
content of static.StaticFiles:
. // IsDir: true
css // IsDir: true
css/bulma.css // IsDir: false
css/bulma.min.css // IsDir: false
```

However, accessing http://localhost:12345/static/css/bulma.css only results in `404 page not found`.

Pointers on what might be missing here are appreciated.

Comment: Your files are in `/css/...`, the request's URL path is looking for `/static/css/...`. That's an obvious mismatch. A common solution is to strip the prefix from the incoming request's URL path. Here's an example https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.20.7#StripPrefix (this one's stdlib-specific, however if you google a bit you should find gorilla-specific examples as well)

Comment: Thanks. But `r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(staticServer)` is supposed to prepend `/static/`, no? And regardless, `http://localhost:12345/css/bulma.css` returns 404 as well. (And the `/css` shall not be stripped, but stay in the path.)

Comment: OK, I stand corrected. The line in questions needs to look like this: `r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", staticServer))`.

Comment: *"... is supposed to prepend /static/, no?"* -- No. And the `http://localhost:12345/css/bulma.css` returns 404 because you don't have a handler registered at `/css/`, instead you have a handler registered at `/static/`, i.e. your gorilla mux accepts only requests with URL paths that start with `/static/` because of `r.PathPrefix("/static/")`.